# extract text without <div> and <p> with xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<tr><td class=term>1st param</td>
    <td>PUTIN 
        <div class='info-icon'>
            <a href='#' onmouseover='show_pd(351);' onmouseout='hide_pd(351);' id='info-icon-351'></a>
        </div>
        <div id='pd-351' style='display: none; position: absolute;'>
        <b>СПРАВКА</b>
        <br /><br />
            <P align=justify><NOBR><STRONG>ABS</STRONG></NOBR>bla-bla-bla text</P>
            <P align=justify>bla-bla-bla text 2</P>
            <P align=justify>bla-bla-bla text 3</P>
            <P align=justify>bla-bla-bla text 4</P>
        </div> 
</td>
```

I need extract only "PUTIN".
Now I'm on

```
//td[@class="term"][contains(text(), "1st param")]/following-sibling::td/[not(self::p)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some adjustments to your XML following XPath

```
//td[@class="term"][contains(text(), "1st param")]/following-sibling::td/node()[1]
```

has the output `PUTIN`

Adjustments were to change `<td class=term>` into `<td class="term">` and all `<P align=justify>` into `<P align="justify">` (maybe not necessary for your settings but was required for the XPath evaluator I just used).

Comment: @EldarZabitov Glad I was able to help you :). If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed. As you maybe don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235